# "No ad to show" kGADAdSizeLeaderboard

Tags: ios, admob

Simply I have downloaded sample project from google DFP admob ([link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples)). It can't seem to get any ads for iPad when using `kGADAdSizeLeaderboard`. I am getting following error:

```
   dfpBannerView_ = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeLeaderboard];
 " Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show."
```

If I use `kGADAdSizeBanner` I get ads from Admob.

Is it possible to get DFP ads working with `kGADAdSizeLeaderboard` while we wait for the adproviders to support smartbanners?

Comment: hi @ravindhiran did you solved this one?

Comment: Same Problem here, did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

There is always the possibility, that there is now ad to show. You should always check for that case and then not display the bannerview.